# Cross Validation with Orange python library

Tags: python, cross-validation, orange, discretization

I try to do cross validation with python package "Orange".
This library looks very nice, but I have some problem with it.

For version information, I use Python 2.7 and Orange 2.7.8.
My task is simple.
I wanna validate model with cross validation with (1) discretization for numeric attributes and (2) feature selection.

Here, it is important to process discretization and feature selection within the cross validation loop, as you know. In other words, for each cross validation loop, (1) discretize only the training data, and use the same binning cut to the test data and (2) get important features from the training data, and use the features for the test data.

After studying the Orange, I coded the following script.

```
import Orange, orange, orngDisc, orngTest, orngStat, orngFSS

data = Orange.data.Table("test.tab") # has numeric, discrete features

nb = Orange.classification.bayes.NaiveLearner()
dBayes = orngDisc.DiscretizedLearner(nb, method=Orange.feature.discretization.Entropy(), name="disc nb")

# feature selection (three important features based on information gain)
fss = orngFSS.FilterBestN(n=3, measure=Orange.feature.scoring.InfoGain())
fBayes = orngFSS.FilteredLearner(dBayes, filter=fss, name="nb & fss")

learners = [nb, dBayes, fBayes]
results = orngTest.crossValidation(learners, data, folds=10, storeClassifiers=1, storeExamples=1)

# print accuracy for the three models (no errors in this block!)
print "\nLearner         Accuracy  #Atts"
for i in range(len(learners)):
  print "%-15s %5.3f     %5.2f" % (learners[i].name, orngStat.CA(results)[i], natt[i])
```

In short, Dataset ("data" in code) contains numeric and discrete features, and I wanna do discretization (based on Entropy), and then feature selection (top 3 features based on the information gain) within the cross validation process.

However, error says that error occured when computing information gain for numeric features. I think that feature selection is processed before discretization.
I think some minor modification is necessary but there aren't plenty of example on the Orange in web... and I have no obvious idea for the modification.

Can you give me some points for the modification?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot use `orngFSS.FilterBestN(n=3, measure=Orange.feature.scoring.InfoGain())` because some of the features are continuous.  The method "feature.scoring.InfoGain" would check whether the features are discreate, refering to [here](https://github.com/zealseeker/orange/blob/master/source/orange/measures.cpp#L523) .

I have two suggestions:

1. Use Classification Tree as learning method and select the top three features in the tree. If the feature is continuous, the classicifation tree will use a discriminant like "A > 0.1" to make the feature discrete.
2. Manually make the features discrete. For example, if age is a feature, then label it 'D' and Orange will regard the feature as discrete. I think it will work